# brown/yellow discoloration on chili leaves

Tags: indoors, chili

Strange discoloration on my chili plant started small but now getting fairly noticeable. Wondering what might cause this.

[image: Here maybe the clearest][image: Here also][image: Under the leaf][image: Some beginning discoloration in other leaves too][image]

Comment: Most of your leaves look very healthy. How many of your leaves are affected? Are only older leaves affected?

Comment: @joy I'd say there are 2 large older leaves (which I just today actually cut off) which are showing the worst signs. The newer leaves are mostly fine, though some older newer leaves appear to be getting some brown spots/discoloration also (visible in the 4th image, now becoming more visible). Also some of my younger chilis now showing some brown spots on their leaves. But another chili of pretty much the same age as this one right next to this seems to show no brown spots.

Comment: Ok, perhaps the adjacent plant is now also showing some spots, but not as much as this one or the very young plant.

Comment: The spots look very odd, and do not match well with the common diseases and infections. Are the affected leaves curling or wilting?

Comment: @joy No other symptoms, other than they were also kind of yellowing when it was bad. Now they look great and have continued growing so really don't know what the issue was. I changed the fertilizer so perhaps that helped, but the fertilizer I used was one I know many chili growers use.